# Copy byte array to not aligned structure

Tags: c++, copy, alignment, byte, structure

Hello trying to understand, why copying byte array to not aligned structure byte by byte i loose some data. Maybe there is a way how to solve it ?

[image]

Sample code bellow:

```
typedef struct {  //Not aligned data
    uint32_t val0;
    uint8_t  val1; 
    uint16_t val2;
    uint32_t val3;
}TestSt_t; 

TestSt_t testSt;
uint8_t testData[16] =  {
    0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44,
    0x55,
    0x66, 0x77,
    0x88, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xBB
};
int main() {
    memcpy((uint8_t*)&testSt, (uint8_t*)&testData[0], sizeof(testSt));
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is lost in padding: `sizeof(TestSt_t)` is 12, not 11.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is adding a byte of [padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing)

```
typedef struct {  //Not aligned data
    uint32_t val0;
    uint8_t  val1; 
        uint8_t padding;
    uint16_t val2;
    uint32_t val3;
}TestSt_t;
```

So `0x66` is in that `padding` byte.

Comment: Is it possible to get a warning or error if compiler adds padding bytes ?

Comment: In GCC there is `-Wpadded`. I bet there must be something similar for VS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4820?view=vs-2019